# How to calculate the number of a day in series of consecutive dates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table

```
id name     created_at
1  name 1   08/01/2017
2  name 2   08/02/2017
3  name 3   08/03/2017
4  name 4   08/05/2017
5  name 5   08/06/2017
6  name 6   08/07/2017
7  name 7   08/10/2017
8  name 8   08/12/2017
```

I need to add a column where be rank for all rows, but if they were created from day to day.

The result should be like below

```
id name     created_at   days_on
1  name 1   08/01/2017   1
2  name 2   08/02/2017   2
3  name 3   08/03/2017   3
4  name 4   08/05/2017   1
5  name 5   08/06/2017   2
6  name 6   08/07/2017   3
7  name 7   08/10/2017   null
8  name 8   08/12/2017   null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands+postgresql) describing typical approaches to similar problems, where you can also find an explanation of the techniques used below.

```
select 
    id, name, created_at, 
    case when count(*) over wa > 1 then row_number() over wo end as rank
from (
    select 
        id, name, created_at, 
        sum(first) over w as part
    from (
        select *, (lag(created_at) over w+ 1 is distinct from created_at)::int as first
        from my_table
        window w as (order by id)
        ) s
    window w as (order by id)
    ) s
window 
    wa as (partition by part),
    wo as (partition by part order by id);
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f640c573187f8be2f632caf0a8e2a5f1)

Comment: @a.kozubenko - I'm afraid I don't get what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: for each row in table this query will run one more query, it means that if I have 100 records it table -  101 request to db

Comment: Still unclear. The query generates exactly one request, regardless of whether the table has 1 or thousands rows.

Comment: N + 1 problem concerns ORM. It's essence is the fact that an incorrectly defined model can generate unnecessary queries. It has nothing to do with the above query. You have just a single query, no additional layers, no ORMs or other obfuscating objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the group-and-islands problem.  Let me show a solution using `lag()` to define the groups:

- `lag()` to get the previous day
- cumulative sum to get the groups
- `row_number()` to assign the final values

This works as:

```
select id, name, created_at,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by grp) > 1
             then row_number() over (partition by grp order by id)
        end) as days_on
from (select t.*,
             sum( (prev_ca <> created_at - interval '1 day')::int ) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(created_at) over (order by id) as prev_ca
            from t
     ) t;
```